# iOS 14 UIDatePicker - allow user to clear value

Tags: ios, uidatepicker, ios14

Within our iOS app, we would like to give the user the option to use the UIDatePicker control but ALSO be able to clear the value after selecting it (the field allows a date OR a blank as the date is optional)

Other than change the field to be a UITextField to be able to add the clear button, is there a native way to add a clear option to the UIDatePicker? I have visions of a dustbin/trashcan on the control

Comment: How the DatePicker looks like currently? Can you put a screenshot?

Comment: I don't believe there is that kind of functionality. But you can do something like (a) default the date picker to something, (b) add the ability to either change or cancel and/or (c) put the entire thing in a popup. For me, this usually begs the following question: Can you show me an app that has the functionality you want? If so, I can probably copy it.